# Sync Windows 8.1 contacts with a Carddav server?

Tags: windows-8.1, contacts

Is there a way I can sync Windows contacts on Windows 8.1 with a Carddav server? There seems only import option available.

Answer (score 0):

On windows phone it seems you can use custom options for the integrated 'icloud account' sync, and use that mechanism to sync with a carddav server you pick, maybe you can try a similar fashion on desktop.
However there is no official support for it.

[carddav via icloud (Windows Phone 8.1)](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-1-preview-developers/275672-cal-carddav-owncloud-wp-8-1-a.html)

Comment: I actually mean windows PC...

Comment: I know, " maybe you can try a similar fashion on desktop."
as I said, no official support but since they are mixing everything up there's a good possibility that could work out on the desktop to.
If not you're going to need a 3th party app to handle these for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I can still not make it happen on Windows desktop.

Comment: you might use one of the apps listed [here](http://carddav.calconnect.org/implementations/clients.html) (or somewhere else) to enable you to view those contacts from your windows desktop. (alternatively you can switch to linux or mac)

Comment: My main OS is actually Linux and OS X, however just need to go to Windows ocassionaly... But anyway, not a big deal, and thanks for the list!